# NFS: How to allow a specific user to write in a NFS mount?

Tags: centos, permissions, nfs

I wrote a Nagios check which is supposed to check the time it takes a server to write a file to one of it's mounts.
The check is being run by user nagios.

The NFS server is configured like so:

```
[root@ny4aftp2 ~]# tail /etc/exports 
/proxy_logs *(rw,insecure,insecure_locks,no_subtree_check,async)
/sync_logs *(rw,insecure,insecure_locks,no_subtree_check,async)
[root@ny4aftp2 ~]# ls -ld /sync_logs/
drwxrwxr-x 3 peeradmin peeradmin 4096 Dec 10 10:14 /sync_logs/
[root@ny4aftp2 ~]#
```

That's the command the check script is running:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/$MOUNTPOINT/`hostname`.dat bs=1024 count=102
```

The client is configured like so:

```
[root@ny4aproxy11 ~]# grep sync /etc/fstab 
IP:/sync_logs /sync_logs nfs intr,noatime  0 0
```

When the check is being run by the nagios user it gets a "Permission denided" error when the `dd` command is trying to write the `.dat` file into the nfs share `/sync_logs` even though the user `nagios` is configured the same in both machines:

Server:

```
[root@ny4aftp2 ~]# id nagios
uid=498(nagios) gid=498(nagios) groups=498(nagios),500(peeradmin)
```

Client:

```
[root@ny4aproxy11 ~]# id nagios
uid=498(nagios) gid=498(nagios) groups=498(nagios),500(peeradmin)
```

And the nagios user is a member of the peeradmin group which is the owner of the `/sync_logs` directory.

`/sync_logs` on the NFS server:

```
[root@ny4aftp2 ~]# ls -ld /sync_logs/
drwxrwxr-x 3 peeradmin peeradmin 4096 Dec 10 10:20 /sync_logs/
```

`/sync_logs` on the NFS client:

```
[root@ny4aproxy11 ~]# ls -ld /sync_logs/
drwxrwxr-x 3 peeradmin peeradmin 4096 Dec 10 10:20 /sync_logs/
```

I wouldn't like to `chmod o+w /sync_logs` , I prefer fixing it like it should be... like the `nagios` user will be getting the permissions from the fact that it is a member of the `peeradmin` group and that will allow the `nagios` user to write to the `/sync_logs` directory.

How can it be done and what am I doing wrong?

Edit #1:

```
IP:/sync_logs on /sync_logs type nfs (rw,noatime,intr,vers=4,addr=SERVER_IP,clientaddr=CLIENT_IP)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you run `mount` what does it say the NFS options are? I'd be guessing that its either root squashing, or NFS id mapping that's at fault. Alternatively - can I suggest checking that $MOUNTPOINT is defined correctly - if that's null, then you'll be trying to write to '/' which _should_ give you 'permission denied'.

Comment: I've verified through `sh -x script` that the $MOUNTPOINT variable gets the correct value.

Comment: OK. Next question then - are these local accounts? If they are, you may need to specify 'sec=sys' as a mount option, because otherwise NFSv4 tries to use usermapping via a directory. (If they're not local, check `idmapd.conf` in `/etc` and check that the domains match).

Comment: These are local account indeed, I'll try setting the `sec=sys` and let you know in a couple of minutes, thanks.

Comment: Shall I add it in the `/etc/fstab` of the client?

Comment: It might be a moot point, as that _might_ be the default. Issuing a 'mount' command by hand should do the trick. (I tend to reserve modifying the fstab until I know my change works).

Comment: Also: Try umounting and checking the permission on the mount point. These may be different - try setting g+rwx and the right gid on there.

Comment: I've tried both `sec=sys` and `chmod g+rwx` on the folder before being mounted... but none worked.

Comment: What was the group owner though? If you made the mount as root, it'd be root:root so g+rwx wouldn't help.

Comment: @Sobrique, The owner user.group was root and as you said, the g+rwx didn't help.

Comment: So `chgrp` the mount to `peeradmin` before mount.

Comment: Just did, then re-mounted and ran the script again but I still get "Permission denied", it looks like that: `/bin/dd: opening `/sync_logs/ny4aproxy11.company.com.dat': Permission denied`

Comment: OK. Backtrack a little. Unmount, then run script. See if that works. (If it does, it's NFS related). Next: mount with vers=3 as an option - this'll mount NFSv3, and tell us if it's an NFSv4 specific problem.

Comment: Okay, it seems like locally the check script works properly but from the Nagios server it doesn't... but that's not related, you solved my issue so please create an answer and it could be nice if you'd explain why the `vers=3` fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Because NFSv3 and NFSv4 use completely different authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Yeah, that means your problem is with the NFSv4 specific components.  I _think_ `idmapd` should work with local accounts, but maybe it doesn't by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments so far:

- your mount works with NFSv3, it doesn't with NFSv3.
- you're using local accounts.

This means that the problem is most likely down to NFSv4 account handling and `idmapd`. What happens in NFSv3 is that your client tells the server what UID and GID you're using.

What happens in NFSv4 is that they use *usernames* and use `idmapd` to map back and forth. This means that you no longer have to have identical UIDs and GIDs across your authentication realm.

But here's the gotcha - `idmapd` needs to be able to do the mapping back and forth. It'll be sending `user@domain` (equivalent) rather than numeric UID/GID.

So check your `/etc/idmapd.conf`. Also check that your domain names on client and host match. You're looking for `domainname` in `idmapd.conf` - if it's not set, it'll default to whatever the `domainname` command on your server/client report.

Switching to NFSv3 may serve as a workaround (and verification) but is probably not a good idea - NFSv4 has some nice enhancements over v3, and turning them off because of an auth problem isn't ideal.